# Struggling to get str_replace to work in R

Tags: r

I'm struggling to get str_replace to work:

Data :

```
test <- structure(list(id_number = 101:106, why_join = c("Support for college success (examples: class selection, managing coursework, time management)", 
"Support for college success (examples: class selection, managing coursework, time management)", 
"Assistance with applying to (and enrolling in) college, Assistance with FASFA/financial aid, Support for college success (examples: class selection, managing coursework, time management), Identifying and enrolling in apprenticeship opportunities, Identifying and enrolling in certification programs", 
"Support for college success (examples: class selection, managing coursework, time management)", 
"Assistance with securing quality employment/career launch, Assistance with applying to (and enrolling in) college, Assistance with FASFA/financial aid, Support for college success (examples: class selection, managing coursework, time management), Identifying and enrolling in apprenticeship opportunities, Identifying and enrolling in certification programs, Interest in military service, Unsure/Exploratory", 
"Assistance with applying to (and enrolling in) college, Assistance with FASFA/financial aid, Support for college success (examples: class selection, managing coursework, time management), Identifying and enrolling in certification programs"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to use `str_replace` to remove "(examples: class selection, managing coursework, time management)" from the strings "Support for college success (examples: class selection, managing coursework, time management)"

Code:

```
test$why_join <- str_replace(test$why_join, "Support for college success (examples: class selection, managing coursework, time management)", "Support for college success")
```

My output is not removing that part of the string. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `str_replace` is in `regex` mode.  Wrap with `fixed` or else the `(`, `)` are judged as metacharacters for capturing groups

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(test$why_join, 
   fixed("Support for college success (examples: class selection, managing coursework, time management)"), 
    "Support for college success")
```

-output

```
[1] "Support for college success"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[2] "Support for college success"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[3] "Assistance with applying to (and enrolling in) college, Assistance with FASFA/financial aid, Support for college success, Identifying and enrolling in apprenticeship opportunities, Identifying and enrolling in certification programs"                                                                                                             
[4] "Support for college success"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[5] "Assistance with securing quality employment/career launch, Assistance with applying to (and enrolling in) college, Assistance with FASFA/financial aid, Support for college success, Identifying and enrolling in apprenticeship opportunities, Identifying and enrolling in certification programs, Interest in military service, Unsure/Exploratory"
[6] "Assistance with applying to (and enrolling in) college, Assistance with FASFA/financial aid, Support for college success, Identifying and enrolling in certification programs"
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you!